# Оибка mysql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, macos, apache2, mac

Даже когда пытаюсь посмотреть версию mysql - `mysql -v`
Выходит ошибка:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dave'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

пытался так:

> $ mysql -u root -p
>
> Enter password: pass...
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

В ЧЕМ ПРОБЛЕМА? Мой комп называется не root. Даже когда вхожу в phpmyadmin выводит ошибку

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Если что компьютер МАКБУК, апаче встроенный, не обновлял

Comment: root - это суперпользователь в mysql. У вас есть пароль к логину root?

Comment: @dmitry-kozlov да, есть, я его поставил при загрузке MySQL

Comment: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" значит неправильный пароль. Раньше работало с этим паролем? Или первый раз после настройки пытаетесь войти?

Comment: Первый раз после Настройки, а как посмотреть пароль тогда ? И почему не работает MySQL -v?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov нет решения?

Comment: Тут похоже, что при установке был введен не тот пароль, который пытаетесь использовать сейчас. Можно попробовать переустановить mysql заново

Answer (score -1):

Решил эту проблему так... нужно изначально войти в mysql с временным паролем и дальше поменять его с терминала...